# How to connect a PlanetScale DB to a SvelteKit app running in Vercel

Tags: svelte, vercel, sveltekit

Vercel and PlanetScale's documentation tell you how to connect them but they have so much automation (read 'magic') happening that if a part fails, you have no clue how to recover.

Something failed so that's where I am.

- Where in Vercel do I put the connection string or username/password?
- Do I install MySQL modules somewhere?
- If so which ones? Where?
- What else am I missing?

**Basically, some brief steps would be very
appreciated.**

(Yes, I've googled it. The only help I can find is connecting Vercel Next.js. Nothing on Vercel SvelteKit that I can see).

Rich Harris? Maybe you can comment?

Answer (score 3):

I'm a Developer Advocate at PlanetScale and a huge fan of SvelteKit and Vercel. To your question about setup, there are a couple of different options.

- use the `mysql2` NPM package which allows you to write raw SQL
- use [Prisma](https://prisma.io/) (an ORM)

My personal preference would be to use Prisma. To me, it adds a more clean way of working with your DB in JavaScript.

As far as where to put the credentials, you'll need to add a `DATABASE_URL` environment variable inside of Vercel. You can find more about environment variables in Vercel [here](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/projects/environment-variables).

This URL will have a slightly different format depending on which NPM package from above you use. You can create them from within the PlanetScale dashboard under the connect dropdown.

Example with Prisma.

[image]

Example with MySQL 2

[image]

Hopefully that helps. Let me know what other questions you have. I'm not the most active on Stack Overflow so feel free to reach out to me on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/jamesqquick) as well.

Comment: that `DATABASE_URL` environment variable in Vercel, should it be the connection string? Do I provide the actual password or the asterisks that I'm seeing under the "Connect" dropdown in PlanetScale?

Comment: @rap I think we've got some work to do on this verbiage, but inside of PlanetScale, you could click to generate a password. The password will several properties, namely username, password, domain, etc. These properties would then be used to create the connection string. So inside of the screenshots above, the connection string is generated for you. So you would copy the connection string from one of those options and paste it into your .env property as `DATABASE_URL`.

Comment: As an example this is what it would look like with Prisma.

`DATABASE_URL=mysql://<USERNAME>:<PLAIN_TEXT_PASSWORD>@<ACCESS_HOST_URL>/<DATABASE_NAME>?sslaccept=strict`